# Guidelines for choosing Array of Struct or Multiple Arrays

Tags: julia

This question has been asked for other languages. I would like to ask this in relation to Julia.

What are the general guidelines for choosing between an array of struct e.g.

```
struct vertex
    x::Real
    y::Real
    gradient_x::Real
    gradient_y::Real
end

myarray::Array{Vertex}
```

and multiple arrays.

```
xpositions::Array{<:Real}
ypositions::Array{<:Real}
gradient_x::Array{<:Real}
gradient_y::Array{<:Real}
```

Are there any performance considerations? Or is it just a style/readability issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `struct` as it currently stands will perform poorly. From the [Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html) you should always:

> Avoid fields with abstract type

Similarly, you should always prefer `Vector{<:Real}` to `Vector{Real}`.

The Julian way to approach this is to parameterize your `struct` as follows:

```
struct Vertex{T<:Real}
    x::T
    y::T
    gradient_x::T
    gradient_y::T
end
```

Given the above, the two approaches discussed in the question will now have roughly similar performance. In practice, it really depends on what kind of operations you want to perform. For example, if you frequently need a vector of just the `x` fields, then having multiple arrays will probably be a better approach, since any time you need a vector of `x` fields from a `Vector{Vertex}` you will need to loop over the structs to allocate it:

```
xvec = [ v.x for v in vertexvec ]
```

On the other hand, if your application lends itself to functions called over all four fields of the struct, then your code will be significantly cleaner if you use a `Vector{Vertex}` and will be just as performant as looping over 4 arrays. Broadcasting in particular will make for nice clean code here. For example, if you have some function:

```
f(x, y, gradient_x, gradient_y)
```

then just add the method:

```
f(v::Vertex) = f(v.x, v.y, v.gradient_x, v.gradient_y)
```

Now if you want to apply it to `vv::Vector{Vertex}`, you can just use:

```
f.(vv)
```

Remember, user-defined types in Julia are just as performant as "in-built" types. In fact, many types that you might think of as in-built are just defined in Julia itself, much as you are doing here.

So the short summary is: both approaches are performant, so use whichever makes more sense in the context of your application.